# Receive a structure with boost socket

Tags: c++, sockets, serialization, boost, boost-asio

I am newer with network programming. I'm trying to send and receive a structure using boost serialization. At the server side, I'm using a vector of structure for sending the information and at the receiver side, I don't know how to receive the vector in a suitable way and deserialize it. Now, I get segmentation fault. Any help is greatly appreciate.

Server side:

```
   struct packet{
        std::string pos;
        int size;
        int Lid;
        int Tid;
        int Qid;
        std::string type;
        std::string disc;
        std::string trunc;
        int nframe;
        template<typename Archive>
            void serialize(Archive&ar, const unsigned int version){
                ar & pos;
                ar &size;
                ar&Lid;
                ar&Tid;
                ar&Qid;
                ar&type;
                ar&disc;
                ar&trunc;
                ar&nframe;
            }
    };

    int main()
    {
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(),50013));
        cout<<"Server waiting for connections: ....."<<endl;

        //send data to the receiver
        for(;;){ //infinite loop(always listening, the session is not closed)
            //creates a socket
            tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            //wait and listen
            acceptor.accept(socket);

            //prepare message to send back to the client
            std::string message="Connection accepted! \n";

            boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
            //write the message
            boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message),ignored_error);

         //open the trace file
                 char pos[20],type[20],trunc[20],disc[20];
                 int L,T,Q,size,nframe;
                 FILE *tracefile;
                 const char * cpath = path.c_str();
                 tracefile=fopen(cpath,"r");
                 fscanf(tracefile,"%s %d %d %d %d %s %s %s %d",pos,&size,&L,&T,&Q,type,disc,trunc,&nframe);
                 std::vector<packet> sendpacket;
                 sendpacket.push_back(packet());

                 string spos(pos);
                 string stype(type);
                 string sdisc(disc);
                 string strunc(trunc);
                 sendpacket[0].pos=spos;
                 sendpacket[0].size=size;
                 sendpacket[0].Lid=L;
                 sendpacket[0].Tid=T;
                 sendpacket[0].Qid=Q;
                 sendpacket[0].type=stype;
                 sendpacket[0].disc=sdisc;
                 sendpacket[0].trunc=strunc;
                 sendpacket[0].nframe=nframe;
                 cout<<sendpacket[0].pos<<endl;
                 cout<<sendpacket[0].size<<endl;

                 socket.send(boost::asio::buffer(sendpacket));


}

    }
```

Receiver Side:

```
struct packet{
    std::string pos;
    int size;
    int Lid;
    int Tid;
    int Qid;
    std::string type;
    std::string disc;
    std::string trunc;
    int nframe;

};

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {

    //Receive the first packet
                 std::vector<packet> receivedpacket;
                //data received from the server
                 socket.receive(boost::asio::buffer(receivedpacket));
                 cout<<receivedpacket[0].pos<<endl;
                 cout<<receivedpacket[0].size<<endl;
                 cout<<receivedpacket[0].Lid<<endl;
                 cout<<receivedpacket[0].Tid<<endl;

    }
```

Comment: You should take care of non pod struct members. These can't be de-/serialized in a simple manner.

Comment: You have made `packet::serialize` presumably in preparation for using boost serialization, but you don't seem to be actually using it.

Comment: What @n.m. said. It's okay to start by copying/emulating. But you have to make sense of it to learn. Boost Serialization is your cue. If you need portable archives, see https://epa.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the serialization example from the boost library examples: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

So now, I am able to send and receive a structure with async_write and async_read. When I send just one packet works well but if I start sending several packets sequentially, the packet is not received at the client side and give me a "Invalid argument" message.

It is like the write and read process are not synchronized or I should use some type of signaling to notify to the server that the client has read all the information successfully and is possible to send the next packet?

Thanks for your help!

Server side:

```
//while(!feof(tracefile)){

    fscanf(tracefile,"%s %d %d %d %d %s %s %s %d",pos,&size,&L,&T,&Q,type,disc,trunc,&nframe);
                     string spos(pos);
                     string sdisc(disc);
                     string stype(type);
                     string strunc(trunc);
        //create the data to be sent to the client
                     pckt.pos=spos;
                     pckt.size=size;
                     pckt.Lid=L;
                     pckt.Tid=T;
                     pckt.Qid=Q;
                     pckt.type=stype;
                     pckt.disc=sdisc;
                     pckt.trunc=strunc;
                     pckt.nframe=nframe;
                     vpacket.push_back(pckt);
        //send the packet to the client. The connection::async_write() function will automatically serialize the data structure for us
                    conn->sendpacket(vpacket,boost::bind(&server::handle_write,this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, conn));
                     cout<<"packet sent"<<endl;
 //}
```

SendPacket function:

```
/// Asynchronously write a data structure to the socket.
  template <typename T, typename Handler>
  void sendpacket(const T& t, Handler handler)
  {
    // Serialize the data first so we know how large it is.
    std::ostringstream archive_stream;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(archive_stream);
    archive << t;
    outbound_data_ = archive_stream.str();

    // Format the header.
    std::ostringstream header_stream;
    header_stream << std::setw(header_length)
      << std::hex << outbound_data_.size();
    if (!header_stream || header_stream.str().size() != header_length)
    {
      // Something went wrong, inform the caller.
      boost::system::error_code error(boost::asio::error::invalid_argument);
      socket_.get_io_service().post(boost::bind(handler, error));
      return;
    }
    outbound_header_ = header_stream.str();

    // Write the serialized data to the socket. We use "gather-write" to send
    // both the header and the data in a single write operation.
    std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers;
    buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outbound_header_));
    buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outbound_data_));
   boost::asio::async_write(socket_,buffers,handler);

  }
```

Receiver Side:

```
//Start operation to read the list
            // of stocks. The connection::async_read() function will automatically
            // decode the data that is read from the underlying socket.
            int nlines; //number of lines tracefile
//for(int j=0;j<nlines;j++){
            connection_.receivepacket(rpacket,
            boost::bind(&client::handle_read, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
//}
```

ReceivePacket function:

```
  /// Asynchronously read a data structure from the socket.
  template <typename T, typename Handler>
  void receivepacket(T& t, Handler handler)
  {
    // Issue a read operation to read exactly the number of bytes in a header.
    void (connection::*f)(
        const boost::system::error_code&,
        T&, boost::tuple<Handler>)
      = &connection::handle_read_header<T, Handler>;
   boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(inbound_header_),
        boost::bind(f,
         this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::ref(t),
          boost::make_tuple(handler)));

  }

  /// Handle a completed read of a message header. The handler is passed using
  /// a tuple since boost::bind seems to have trouble binding a function object
  /// created using boost::bind as a parameter.
  template <typename T, typename Handler>
  void handle_read_header(const boost::system::error_code& e,
      T& t, boost::tuple<Handler> handler)
  {
    if (e)
    {
      boost::get<0>(handler)(e);
    }
    else
    {
      // Determine the length of the serialized data.
      std::istringstream is(std::string(inbound_header_, header_length));
      std::size_t inbound_data_size = 0;
      if (!(is >> std::hex >> inbound_data_size))
      {
        // Header doesn't seem to be valid. Inform the caller.
        boost::system::error_code error(boost::asio::error::invalid_argument);
        boost::get<0>(handler)(error);
        return;
      }

      // Start an asynchronous call to receive the data.
      inbound_data_.resize(inbound_data_size);
      void (connection::*f)(
          const boost::system::error_code&,
          T&, boost::tuple<Handler>)
        = &connection::handle_read_data<T, Handler>;
     boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(inbound_data_),
       boost::bind(f, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::ref(t), handler));

    }
  }

/// Handle a completed read of message data.
  template <typename T, typename Handler>
  void handle_read_data(const boost::system::error_code& e,
      T& t, boost::tuple<Handler> handler)
  {
    if (e)
    {
      boost::get<0>(handler)(e);
    }
    else
    {
      // Extract the data structure from the data just received.
      try
      {
        std::string archive_data(&inbound_data_[0], inbound_data_.size());
        std::istringstream archive_stream(archive_data);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(archive_stream);
        archive >> t;
      }
      catch (std::exception& e)
      {
        // Unable to decode data.
        boost::system::error_code error(boost::asio::error::invalid_argument);
        boost::get<0>(handler)(error);
        return;
      }

      // Inform caller that data has been received ok.
      boost::get<0>(handler)(e);
    }
  }

private:
  /// The underlying socket.
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;

  /// The size of a fixed length header.
  enum { header_length = 8 };

  /// Holds an outbound header.
  std::string outbound_header_;

  /// Holds the outbound data.
  std::string outbound_data_;

  /// Holds an inbound header.
  char inbound_header_[header_length];

  /// Holds the inbound data.
  std::vector<char> inbound_data_;
```